# fix file not found in Sonar JaCoCo reporting

Tags: sonarqube, jacoco

I would like to solve the warnings in my Sonar log:

```
INFO: Sensor Groovy JaCoCo [groovy]
INFO:   Checking binary directory: /home/project/target/classes
INFO: Analysing /home/project/target/jacoco.exec
INFO: Analysing /home/project/target/jacoco.exec
WARN: File not found: utils/Rule.groovy
WARN: File not found: com/acme/manager/Command.groovy
WARN: File not found: com/acme/manager/util/YamlReader.groovy
WARN: File not found: steps/DeployTest.groovy
WARN: File not found: /deploy.groovy
```

My settings are:

```
x.sonar.projectBaseDir=.
x.sonar.sources=src,vars
x.sonar.tests=test/groovy
x.sonar.test.exclusions=test/groovy/com/acme/manager
```

Some of the warnings are due to exclusions files (these files are evaluated in another Sonar module). But others should be no issue. Any idea whats going wrong here?

In the Sonar I get coverage for files under `src/com/acme/anything` but not from the `vars` folder (`default` package). In the JaCoCo html report however, I have the `default` package and coverage for the `vars` folder.

Answer (score 1):

The `File not found` warnings are written by the [AbstractAnalyzer.java](https://github.com/pmayweg/sonar-groovy/blob/master/sonar-groovy-plugin/src/main/java/org/sonar/plugins/groovy/jacoco/AbstractAnalyzer.java#L82) class of the SonarGroovy plugin. As far as I understand, the plugin successfully found your jacoco.exec results (which contains those file paths like `utils/Rule.groovy` that it fails to find).

Probably you did not set your `sonar.sources` correctly, it should include a path to your groovy source code and also include the `vars` folder if you have Groovy source code there. By default, `sonar.sources` is set to `src` only and the code your `vars` folder may therefore not be found. You could try adding the missing folders to the sources like this:

```
sonar.sources=src,vars
```

The property `sonar.groovy.binaries` is also needed for Groovy code coverage (it should point to the compiled groovy class files), if you don't set it explicitly then `sonar.binaries` will be used to find the Groovy binaries. The following quote from the [SonarGroovy plugin](https://github.com/pmayweg/sonar-groovy#notes) website may also be helpful:

> The groovy plugin requires access to source binaries when analyzing JaCoCo reports. Consequently, property `sonar.groovy.binaries` has to be configured for the analysis (comma-separated paths to binary folders). For Maven and gradle projects, the property is automatically set.

Comment: We use Maven so I trust that `sonar.groovy.binaries` is set automatically.

Comment: I updated my answer. You may have to explicitly make Sonar aware of the existence of other folders that contain source code. By default, it searches only the `src` folder.

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile I found reasons for some of the messages:

1. `File not found: /deploy.groovy`: due to an issue in the file handling in the [sonar groovy plugin](https://github.com/pmayweg/sonar-groovy) empty packages are not handled correctly, see [issue #73](https://github.com/pmayweg/sonar-groovy/issues/73)
2. `File not found: steps/DeployTest.groovy`: test files need to be listed under `sonar.source` to be recognised. However, if `tests/groovy` is added to `sonar.source` it may not be added to `sonar.tests`, causing resource issues in the *GroovySurefireSensor:* `WARN: Resource not found: steps/DeployTest.groovy`